Kitten stealing other cat's food and fighting them
I have- or my family has an kitten (we dont know how old) and they are keep stealing the other cat's food even if their bowel has food or not. We tried to make the kitten not take the food by saying "bad cat!" or by screaming their name. They know their name because they came to us for food when we called it. At first, we just told them, "Don't do that!" or just pushed them away, but it didn't work. The kitten also goes and beats up, or at least plays fights with the older cat. This is causing the cat to want to go outside to be away from the kitten, but here is the problem: Due to the kitten stealing the older cat's food, the cat got skinny and stuff and was way less tall or big, and since the cat now wants to go outside more often, the cat gets even skinnier. What do we do about this behavior from the kitten? This has been going on for about a year now. Another problem is that the older cat doesn't want to "play fight" with the kitten, making the cat go outside even more! We need help.

Also, the kitten might be getting overweight because of this problem.

